# Regex Notepad ++ find lines with exclude

Tags: notepad++

How i can find lines:

```
`https://somesite.com/upload/file.jpg`
```

in Notepad ++ using Regex but exclude

```
`https://somesite.com/upload/folder/file.jpg`
```

Select form https://somesite.com/upload/ to .jpg but exclude selection if between will be "/"

Comment: exclude the whole line or just 'folder/'? Meanwhile, here's a great tool: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What is the logic behind why the first line is included but the second excluded?

Comment: @zergski I need to exclude from selection lines that will have / between /upload/ to .jpg so it will select only lines that have /upload/file.jpg and exclude /upload/somefolder/file.jpg

Comment: I made this upload(.+?).jpg but it still select lines https://somesite.com/upload/folder/file.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using this pattern:

```regex
https?://.*/upload/[^/.]+\.jpg
```

This would match any URL ending with the path `upload`, which is then followed by some JPEG filename.

### Demo

Comment: not working it select all lines from start to end.

Comment: @c64girl Uncheck the box which says "dot matches across newlines."  Then it should work.

Comment: Working. Thank You it seems i missed it.